# Problem in swirl package learning function

Tags: r

The last R expression to be evaluated in a function will become the return value of that function. We want this function to take one argument, x, and return x without modifying it. Delete the pound sign so that x is returned without any modification. Make sure to save your script before you type submit().

There is a problem with swirl package, where the function learning section gives the problem related to boring function

Comment: This is really hard to tell. Could you provide more details? Like what code you ran?

Comment: Could you please give reproducible numerical example?

Answer (score 0):

I found that problem extremely fustrating you can type skip(). I found that if I saved the file: ie summerize1.R before I entered submit(); then it will work.  There must be a failure somewhere between my tempfiles and the swirl updating them.  i am not experienced enough to figure that one out but saving the file works.  I hvae tried it on Gathering and filtering and the tydr one as well.

Answer (score 0):

If you mean the problem where the submit function is not found, you can run it directly from the swirl package.

```
> submit()
Error in submit() : could not find function "submit"
> swirl::submit()
```